# javascript error tracking service built on a free cloud datastore

Tags: javascript, web-services, parse-platform

I am contemplating building a javascript error tracking service like [errorception.com](http://errorception.com) that will track client side errors. I want to use [parse.com](http://parse.com)'s free plan of 1,000,000 API requests per month and thus be able to provide this service as a self contained deployable js file.

does something like this already exist? Ive seen a few js error tracking services but none of them are free.

Answer (score 1):

You could host your own using [errbit](https://github.com/errbit/errbit). It is open source and is compatible with the [Airbrake](http://airbrakeapp.com) (formerly Hoptoad) API.

Obviously this is not entirely free, as you have to pay for hosting costs.